# Jquery and object href confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried adding console.log, but I can't figure it out.

```
$(this).href
```

Doesn't this refer to the end link location?

As in if

```
<a href="test.php">here</a>
```

And the page we are on is test.com
Does $(this).href give us "test.php" or test.com/test.php? I need to access the latter of the two.

Any tips?

Comment: I tried changing $(this).href to $(this.href) and it gives me other errors.

Comment: `this.href`  will give you the `href`. Why are you creating a jQuery object?

Comment: jQuery collection vs DOM element: `$(this).attr('href')` or `this.getAttribute('href')`. [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/), good stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` is a jQuery object, and doesn't have the property of `href`.

You should either use `$(this).attr('href')` or `this.href`.

The difference is that `$(this).attr('href')` returns `'test.php'`,
and `this.href` returns `'http(s?)://test.com/test.php'`

Comment: Wait... so should i get rid of the $() surrounding this?

Comment: @jiexi Depend on what you need, if you want to access the property of the dom element, you should not wrap it with $().

Comment: you can get the property form the element in a jQuery collection.  Maybe you could avoid it, but it's not true that you should never do it.  You might very well want to get the property from the first item in the collection and jQuery is a good way to do that.  Or you might already be in a jQuery loop (each / map).  In that case use `$(this).prop('href');` Here is a 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/ehKYq/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$(this).attr("href")
```

This will return whatever is in the tag's href itself:

```
<a href="test.php">here</a>
```

will give:

```
test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

No!

When you query using $, that returns a jQuery object.

If you try:

```
$(this).get(0).href
```

It can return the Element object relative to your link, and return the correct attribute.

But, a more beautiful method of getting a attribute is something such as:

```
$(this).attr("href");
```

And the `this` keyword is only valid in the context of the link (such as when you are using it in a function that listen to a event in the link)